# RoutingError on Ruby Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey everyone, thanks for reading this. 
Ihave the next issue: When I call my "New" template (generated by scaffold) I got the next error:

```
<h1>ActionController::RoutingError in Flujos_de_trabajo#new</h1>

Showing app/views/flujos_de_trabajo/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

flujos_de_trabajo_url failed to generate from {:controller=>"flujos_de_trabajo", :action=>"show"} - you may have ambiguous routes, or you may need to supply additional parameters for this route.  content_url has the following required parameters: ["flujos_de_trabajo", :id] - are they all satisfied?

Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h1>New flujo_de_trabajo</h1><br/>
2: <br/>
3: <% form_for(@flujo_de_trabajo) do |f| %><br/>
4:   <%= f.error_messages %><br/>
5: <br/>
6:   <p><br/>
```

I have overlooked everything, and I don't know what the problem is. The code in the view and in the controller is the same as the generated. In fact, i deleted it, generated it againg, and nothing, the same problem. Can you help me?

Comment: if you have a routing error, it would be nice to see your `routes.rb`

Comment: Is all you did just `script/generate scaffold`? Did you remember to `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you do this.

1. script/generate scaffold FlujosDeTrabajo
2. rake db:migrate
3. http://localhost:3000/flujos_de_trabajos/new

it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Rails is really bad for languages that aren't English. It's failing here because it thinks that "flujo_de_trabajo" is the singular version of "flujo_de_trabajo". You're going to have to set up some inflections telling Rails the correct singular version of this. Look at the examples in *config/initializers/inflectors.rb*.